# how to convert array of object with objects inside to array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this array:

```
var test = [{
    t1: {a:1, b:2, ...},
    t2: {a:3, b:4, ...},
...,
},{
    t3: {a:5, b:6, ...},
    t4: {a:7, b:8, ...},
...,
}]
```

and I want it to look like this:

```
var test = [{a:1, b:2, ...},{a:3, b:4, ...},{a:5, b:6, ...},{a:7, b:8, ...}, ...]
```

Comment: That's an invalid js object (desired output).

Comment: Do you mean: `[{t1:{test:1}},{t2:{test:2}},{t3:{test:3}},{t4:{test:4}]}`?

Comment: @Ele I've just fixed the mistakes

Comment: Done! see the answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the function `reduce` and then concatenate every object's values.

```js
var test = [{    t1: {a:1, b:2},    t2: {a:3, b:4},},{    t3: {a:5, b:6},    t4: {a:7, b:8}}],
    result = test.reduce((a, c) => a.concat(Object.values(c)), []);

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```